# Separar uma coluna a partir da quantidade de caracteres no R

Tags: r, string, caracteres

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero dividir a variável CAUSABAS em duas, separando as letras dos números. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 2):

Eis uma solução com o novo operador pipe introduzido com o R 4.1 e com `tidyr::separate`.

```r
dados <- data.frame(CAUSABAS = c("O670", "O670", "B208", "O994"))

dados |>
  tidyr::separate(CAUSABAS, into = c("letra", "num"), sep = 1)
#>   letra num
#> 1     O 670
#> 2     O 670
#> 3     B 208
#> 4     O 994
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>